# syntax highlight within a text file?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a text file with code snippets scattered here and there.

Is there a way to have syntax highlight for the code snippets ?

(all snippets are in the same language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
:set syntax=<language>
```

to force some syntax coloring.

-- Yet it might be chaotic if the remaining text has some elements that conflict (unmatched quotes for instance)

Comment: The problem with conflicting elements in the text is precisely what I want to avoid.  I was hoping maybe there would be a plugin or perhaps a 'trick' with markers ?

Comment: Then you might want to look at this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks Ptival

Comment: `=javascript` is too chaotic.